# import hard wallet to bitcoin core

Tags: bitcoin-core

I'd like to hold my bitcoin on coinbase in a hard wallet. they explain that you can onyl do that by importing a hard wallet to online one like Bitcoincore. but how do you do that? import a hard external wallet to bitcore? thanks
bet its a  common question!

Comment: By "hard wallet" do you mean a hardware wallet like Trezor or Ledger?

Comment: Yes thank you, In this case Ledger Nano. So what i downloaded Bitcoin Core to my PC. I thought I needed to get it working before I linked it to the ledger (which installed earlier with no problem).
So Bitcoin Core then took all day to update to the current date. And every time i turn it back on it has to update again. So it never reaches the present day. Sooner or later the PC closes down while I'm elsewhere. I sent a very small amount of bitcoins as a test. Bitcoin.com says they're gone but I have no way of seeing if they arrived at bitcoin core as it never finishes. Help!

Comment: You don't need Bitcoin Core if all you want to do is send your bitcoins from Coinbase (see note later) to a Ledger Nano S. You would just do a withdrawal of your bitcoins, giving Coinbase the receiving address supplied by the Ledger. Note: I have read that for withdrawal, it's better to transfer your coins from Coinbase to the GDAX exchange (which is part of the Coinbase company) because GDAX charges no transaction fee for withdrawals. I have no personal experience with transactions on Coinbase or GDAX.

Comment: Thanks. Coinbase does say it doesn't send to hard wallets

Comment: (Responding to your misplaced "Answer".) Coinbase has no way of knowing what it's sending to.